# Rewriting this logic expression to NAND only ports

Tags: logic-gates, circuit-design, boolean-algebra

I have made a logic expression for the J2 input of a JK flipflop using truthtable and karnaugh map (see truthtable below), but now I want to rewrite it using boolean algebra to get an expression that only includes NAND-ports

Truthtable:

[image]

[image]

(1st expression is the one that needs to be simplified, 2nd expression is the solution)

EDIT3: found this expression and circuit, can anyone confirm that this is the most optimal NAND-gate solution (least ammount of gates)?

[image]

Comment: Have a go at drawing out the circuit - and think about how you might make an inverter from a nand gate.

Comment: @stefandz I tried (see picture above), the solution should include 6 nand gates, but I keep getting 7 of them

Comment: I am slightly confused by your original equations by the way (they aren't labelled as I would expect) - could you draw out the truth table that you think applies to the system and define the inputs? For example, I would expect a J-K FF to have inputs labelled J, K and outputs labelled Q and Q'. What are A1, A2 and Q1 here?

Comment: You missed a simplification before you converted to OR to NAND. What do the first two terms have in common?

Comment: Memories and boolean logic are not compatible(as in you can't design a latch/flipflop with boolean logic expressions) anyways. the expression should be (A1 NAND Q )NAND A2

Comment: @stefandz I added the truthtable now, the boolean logic expression for the J2 input is the one I'm trying to rewrite to nand only gates.
The equations I obtained from this problem: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234383/karnaugh-map-question/234448#234448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to work through this to the best of my ability - according to the excellent hint in the answer from Tom Carpenter's answer.

We start with

\$X = A_2 \overline A_1 + \overline Q_1  A_2 + Q_1 \overline A_2 A_1\$

which we can write as

\$ X = A_2(\overline A_1 + \overline Q_1) + Q_1 \overline A_2A_1 \$

and hence

\$ X = A_2(\overline{\overline{\overline A_1 + \overline Q_1}}) + Q_1 \overline A_2A_1 \$

then we can remove line redundancy and apply de Morgan's rule

\$ X = A_2(\overline{ A_1 Q_1}) + Q_1 \overline A_2A_1 \$

now add two more bars over the entire statement

\$ X = \overline { \overline { A_2(\overline{ A_1 Q_1}) + Q_1 \overline A_2A_1 }}\$

and then reapply de Morgan's rule

\$ X = \overline { \overline { A_2(\overline{ A_1 Q_1})} \cdot \overline {Q_1 \overline A_2A_1 }}\$

We can then draw this out as:

> [image: schematic]

This is just 5 gates, and going through the truth table seems to show that the functionality is as required.

Answer (score 2):

There are more ways of simplifying things than just de Morgan's rule.

Just like in multiplication/addition, there are also associativity and commutatively rules, for example:

$$A + B + C = (A+B) + C$$
$$A\cdot C + B\cdot C = C\cdot(A+B)$$

If you use those relationships in your simplification you do indeed end up with only 6 gates. It may be possible to get fewer still with care (seems 5 is possible from the comments).

> Hint: What do the first two terms of the original expression have in common?

Comment: Thanks, your hint simplified it some more, but now I end up with 5 gates, did I miss something?

Comment: I end up with 5 gates too, and I am happy that matches the original equation truth table...

Comment: It's entirely possible you got 5, I didn't spend a much time trying to simplify it beyond 6.